# VBA: my program is throwing compile error on Format

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, arguments, byref

So I'm working with my program. It works and runs, so I copied it and made a second version which I can add extra features to while still having a working program. I don't see any problems with my new code, so I prepare to step thru it. Suddenly things which work perfectly fine in my other version are throwing compile errors. Specifics below.

```
Dim elapsedTime As String
Dim startTime As Date
startTime = Now()
'code
elapsedTime = Format(Now() - startTime, "h:m:s")
```

I checked again and again, but this exact same code works fine in my other file. In this file, it highlights "Format" and throws the following Compile Error.
[image: Compile Error: arguments or property]

Does anyone know why excel would be getting so upset at this? If there are compile errors, should I even be looking at the places it highlights at all?

Comment: Would you happen to have a `Format` function somewhere in-scope? Does qualifying it (e.g. `VBA.Strings.Format`) fix it? As for the `ByRef` mismatch, does changing the signature to `ByVal eqn As String` change anything? That said this is really two questions - you should pick one and make a *specific* post, titled as per e.g. what you would google up to find a solution for that specific problem. That way your question (and its answers) will be useful for other people, which is what this site is for.

Comment: (a) Did you create a `Format` function that does not take two parameters?  Or a variable called `Format`? (b) The part of your code visible behind the `eqn` error message does not line up with what is in your posted code (there's a comment line above the statement in the image).  Are you sure the posted code is the section that is failing?  (That `Trendline` Sub doesn't give me any compile errors.)

Comment: @YowE3K ha, good eye!

Comment: Thinking a bit more about the `Format` issue, try clicking on `Format` and press Shift+F2 - see where it takes you (it will either take you to your own `Format` definition, or to the library definition)

Comment: Are you sure that starttime is less than now()? I think it might be greater than starttime, So you are getting negative value and so the error.

Comment: FWIW, if the VBE is throwing a compile error, *there's a compile error*.

Comment: @Valli `Format` doesn't give an error for a negative date value (e.g. `Format(Now() - (Now() + 10.1682736), "dd/mm/yyyy h:m:s")`, which is subtracting a time about 10+ days into the future from the current time, will give `20/12/1899 4:2:19`).  But the OP's code is subtracting an earlier time from the current time, so it shouldn't be negative anyway

Comment: @Mat'sMug I took your advice and made a separate post for my second question and changed this to be just the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have something named `Format` *somewhere* that's in-scope (i.e. accessible from where that `Format` function is being invoked), and that `Format` thing is *shadowing* the `Format` function you mean to call.

As [YowE3K suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593912/vba-my-program-is-throwing-compile-errors-that-arent#comment80141380_46593912) if you right-click on that `Format` call and  select "Definition" (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), that will take you to the shadowing declaration.

From there you have several options:

- Rename the `Format` identifier [and possibly break a ton of things in your code]
- Fully-qualify *that* `Format` call, i.e. `VBA.Strings.Format`, or just `Strings.Format`, or even `VBA.Format`.

My suggestion would be to fully-qualify *that* call, then try to compile again, and fully-qualify *any/all* calls that cause that same compile error. *Then* rename whatever it is that is named `Format`, so that it no longer *shadows* the function from the VBA standard library.

If you're using [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage), you can easily locate all references of the shadowing identifier:

[image: Rubberduck toolbar showing all references]

The Rubberduck toolbar tells you when `Format` is referring to the correct function:

[image: Rubberduck toolbar showing VBA.Strings.Format]

And you can easily locate all references to that as well, qualified or not - so it's easy to fully-qualify them wherever they are.

Rubberduck also makes it easy to refactor/rename the function, in a way that search/replace fails:

[image: "Format" function renamed to "Renamed", VBA.Strings.Format call remained unchanged]

Coincidentally, a new code inspection is currently in works, specifically to locate *shadowing identifiers* like this.

---

As for the `ByRef` argument type mismatch, it seems your screenshot doesn't match with the code you posted, so anything is possible, but unless `eqn` is assigned in the body of that `MakeEqn` function (it should be *returned*, not *assigned*), then there's no need to pass it `ByRef` (implicitly or explicitly) - it can be passed `ByVal` (Rubberduck gives you an inspection result for that - and another for the implicit return type, and another for the implicit `Public` access modifier on both procedures, and several others for other issues in the code you posted).

Comment: LOL - I would call this out for blatant self-promotion except (a) you declare your interest in the "product" you refer to, and (b) you don't do it very often, and (most importantly!) (c) *using Rubberduck is almost certainly the best way to resolve the OP's issues*.

Comment: Had it not been for RD I'd have not known about all the improvements I could make to my own code. *Disclaimer: I'm a RD contributor.* If RD were used prior to commented I truly do believe the user would be able to resolve most of their own coding problems.

Comment: You mention it a bit in comments (but only when such a comment would be useful) but I rarely see it mentioned in actual answers.  And, if SO decided it was too "self-promotional", they shouldn't run the occasional community ad for it! :D

Comment: You were exactly right, I did create a format sub in my tweaking. I hadn't even thought about it being a reserved method. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!